# Hosting API With Ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu

I have used Ubuntu to host websites in php before, but now I have created a C# VS API that I clicked my project and went to Publish and copied the files over to my `/var/www/` directory thinking that it would be that simple for my api to launch.  (of course I have apache installed and configured).  However, when I navigate to the IP address instead of getting my API I generated I get a `Index of /` page showing the contents of the directory.

Is there a special setting needed in Ubuntu to be able to run an API?  Did I not correctly generate the needed files from Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: Well, did you install the .NET Core Runtime, including the hosting parts? Normally, the best you can do regarding ASP.NET Core is to read the official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1